# Powershell - JSON syntax of braces within braces

Tags: json, powershell

Powershell 5.1 - I'm using `Invoke-RestMethod` to `POST` data to an endpoint.

The body of the API call looks like this in JSON:

```
{
  "ServiceKind": "Custom",
  "ApplicationName": "TestApp",
  "ServiceName": "TestService",
  "ServiceTypeName": "TestServiceType",
  "PartitionDescription": {
    "PartitionScheme": "Singleton"
  },
  "InstanceCount": "1"
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct in Powershell, and it appears to be related to the PartitionDescription key.

Here is what I have, which continues to throw an error when run:

```
    $ServiceKind = 'Custom'
    $ApplicationName = 'TestApp'
    $ServiceName = 'TestService'
    $ServiceTypeName = 'TestServiceType'
    $PartitionDescription = "{PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'}"
    $InstanceCount = '1'
    $url = 'https://www.contoso.com'
    $headers = 'our headers'
    $bodyTest = @{
       ServiceKind = $ServiceKind
       ApplicationName = $ApplicationName
       ServiceName = $ServiceName
       ServiceTypeName = $ServiceTypeName
       PartitionDescription = $PartitionDescription
                 }

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -body $body -Method Post -ContentType ‘application/json’
```

Error Message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"Error":{"Code":"E_INVALIDARG","Message":"The request body can't be deserialized. Make sure it contains a valid PartitionedServiceDescWrapper object."}}
```

I'm certain it has to do with the `$PartitionDescription` value, but I'm unable to get any syntax to work correctly. If I pass the API call **without** the `$body` parameter I don't get any error.

Comment: Same way as with the _outer_ set of brackets :) `$PartitionDescription = @{PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks but I get the same error doing it that way.

Comment: something specific to the API, try `[array]$PartitionDescription =@{PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'}`

Comment: Try `$PartitionDescription = @{PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'}` and then `$bodyTest | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not nesting your object correctly:

```
$body = @{
    ServiceKind          = 'Custom'
    ApplicationName      = 'TestApp'
    ServiceName          = 'TestService'
    ServiceTypeName      = 'TestServiceType'
    PartitionDescription = @{
        PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'
    }
    InstanceCount        = '1'
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

To improve this even further:

```
$irmParams = @{
    Uri         = 'https://www.contoso.com'
    Method      = 'POST'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers     = @{ Key = 'Value' }

    Body        = @{
        ServiceKind          = 'Custom'
        ApplicationName      = 'TestApp'
        ServiceName          = 'TestService'
        ServiceTypeName      = 'TestServiceType'
        PartitionDescription = @{
            PartitionScheme = 'Singleton'
        }
        InstanceCount        = '1'
    } | ConvertTo-Json
}
Invoke-RestMethod @irmParams
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the improvement syntax - great suggestion.